# How to intercept send() or render() in Node.js express route

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

In my node.js express app, I have index route that sends an array of image urls to view using `render()`

I want to be able to detect dimensions of those images before it gets loaded on the page to prepare placeholder boxes in those sizes.

What is the process of such a task?

My guess is that the app only gets to know the image dimensions of those image urls once they are rendered on the page so is it even possible to know the dimensions before they are rendered?

Answer (score 1):

these modules may help
`github.com/netroy/image-size`

`github.com/EyalAr/lwip` (if u want to resize scale and all)

And as long as intercepting is considered u may override send() and render() , or create a common route, do some processing and call next() , just a middleware

hope this helps